# What means "table A left outer join table B ON TRUE"?

Tags: sql, join, select

I know conditions are used in table joining. But I met a specific situation and the SQL codes writes like "`Table A join table B ON TRUE`"

What will happen based on the "ON TRUE" condition? Is that just a total cross join without any condition selection?

Actually, the original expression is like:

```
Table A LEFT outer join table B on TRUE
```

Let's say A has m rows and B has n rows. Is there any conflict between "left outer join" and "on true"? Because it seems "on true" results a cross join.

From what I guess, the result will be m*n rows. So, it has no need to write "left outer join", just a "join" will give the same output, right?

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 16):

Yes. That's the same thing as a `CROSS JOIN`.

In MySQL, we can omit the [optional] `CROSS` keyword. We can also omit the `ON` clause.

The condition in the `ON` clause is evaluated as a boolean, so we could also jave  written something like  `ON 1=1`.

---

**UPDATE:**

(The question was edited, to add another question about `a LEFT [OUTER] JOIN b` which is different than the original construct: `a JOIN b`)

The "`LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`" is slightly different, in that rows from the table on the left side will be returned even when there are no matching rows found in the table on the right side.

As noted, a `CROSS JOIN` between tables **a** (containing *m* rows) and table **b** containing *n* rows, absent any other predicates, will produce a resultset of *m* x *n* rows.

The `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` will produce a different resultset in the special case where table **b** contains 0 rows.

```
CREATE TABLE a (i INT);
CREATE TABLE b (i INT);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (1),(2),(3);

SELECT a.i, b.i FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON TRUE ;
```

Note that the LEFT JOIN will returns rows from table a (a total of *m* rows) even when table b contains 0 rows.

Comment: Thanks. What if the expression is "Table A LEFT outer join table B on TRUE" Is the result the same? like m*n rows?

Answer (score 3):

The `join` syntax's general form:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_a
JOIN   table_b ON condition
```

The `condition` is used to tell the database how to match rows from `table_a` to `table_b`, and would usually look like `table_a.some_id = table_b.some_id`.

If you just specify `true`, you will match every row from `table_a` with every row of `table_b`, so if `table_a` contains n rows and `table_b` contains m rows the result would have m*n rows.

Most(?) modern databases have a cleaner syntax for this, though:

```
SELECT     *
FROM       table_a
CROSS JOIN table_b
```

Comment: What if there is a row in table_a that has zero matching values from table_b? Would it have n rows from `table_b` that are all null matched to that one row? Thanks.

Comment: @BowenLiu if the condition is "true" (or you use a cross join), there is no such thing as a row with no matches - **all** the rows from table a match **all** the rows from table b, regardless of their content

Comment: Thanks. You got me thinking about the `ON condition` part. So we can also pass a query like `LEFT JOIN...ON table_a.columnA > table_b.columnB`, and only the rows that meet the condition will be joined?

Answer (score 2):

A cross join produces a cartesian product between the two tables, returning all possible combinations of all rows. It has no on clause because you're just joining everything to everything.

Cross join does not combine the rows, if you have 100 rows in each table with 1 to 1 match, you get 10.000 results, Innerjoin will only return 100 rows in the same situation.

These 2 examples will return the same result:

Cross join

```
select * from table1 cross join table2 where table1.id = table2.fk_id
```

Inner join

```
select * from table1 join table2 on table1.id = table2.fk_id
```

Use the last method

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the pure *cross join* and *left join* (where the condition is forced to be always true, as when using ON TRUE) is that the result set for the *left join* will also have rows where the left table's rows appear next to a bunch of NULLs where the right table's columns would have been.