# JOIN (SELECT ... ) ue ON 1=1?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join, amazon-redshift

I am reading an SQL query in Redshift and can't understand the last part:

```
...
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MIN(modified) AS first_modified FROM user) ue
ON 1=1
```

What does `ON 1=1` mean here?

Comment: It just ensures the `join` will return a match -- `1=1` is the same as `true`.  Given the subquery, it will only return a single row -- `min(modified)`.  That value will be combined to the other joins.  Almost acts like a `cross join`, but with only a single value.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's simply doing a cross join, which selects all rows from the first table and all rows from the second table and shows as cartesian product, i.e. with all possibilities.

JOIN (LEFT, INNER, RIGHT, etc.) statements normally require an 'ON ..." condition. Putting in 1=1 is like saying "1=1 is always true, do don't eliminate anything".

Comment: It's not exactly `cross join`, because when right table returns no rows, `cross join` will return also no rows, but `left join on 1=1` will return all rows from left table with null values as a right table. So be carefull with rewriting.

Comment: `join on true` and `left join on true` is different, as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21520048/what-means-table-a-left-outer-join-table-b-on-true

Answer (score 55):

The intention is an *unconditional* `LEFT JOIN`, which is ***different*** from a `CROSS JOIN` in that all rows from the left table expression are returned, even if there is no match in the right table expression - while a `CROSS JOIN` drops such rows from the result. [More on joins in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM)

However:

**`1=1` is pointless** in Postgres and [all derivatives](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_derived_databases) including Amazon Redshift. Just use `true`. This has probably been carried over from another RDBMS that does not support the [`boolean`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-boolean.html) type properly.

```
... LEFT JOIN (SELECT  ...) ue ON true
```

Then again, `LEFT JOIN` is pointless for this particular subquery with `SELECT MIN(modified) FROM user` on the right, because a `SELECT` with an aggregate function (`min()`) and no `GROUP BY` clause always returns exactly one row. This case (but not other cases where ***no row*** might be found) can be simplified to:

```
... CROSS JOIN (SELECT MIN(modified) AS first_modified FROM user) ue
```

Answer (score 14):

My answer illustrates on top of Erwin's answers with an example.

Suppose you have three tables A1, B1, & C1(empty)

A1 -

```
+-+
|a|
+-+
|2|
|1|
|3|
+-+
```

B1 -

```
+----+
|b   |
+----+
|a   |
|b   |
|c   |
|NULL|
+----+
```

C1 -

```
+----+
|c   |
+----+
```

When joining table A1 & B1, `on 1=1` behaves same as `CROSS JOIN`.

```
select * from a1 left join b1 on 1=1;
select * from a1 cross join b1;
```

Result -

```
+-+----+
|a|b   |
+-+----+
|1|NULL|
|1|a   |
|1|b   |
|1|c   |
|2|NULL|
|2|a   |
|2|b   |
|2|c   |
|3|NULL|
|3|a   |
|3|b   |
|3|c   |
+-+----+
```

However, when we join A1 with C1, you get two different results

```
select * from a1 left join c1 on 1=1;
```

Result -

```
+-+----+
|a|c   |
+-+----+
|1|NULL|
|3|NULL|
|2|NULL|
+-+----+
```

For cross join -

```
select * from a1 cross join c1;
```

Result -

```
+-+-+
|a|c|
+-+-+
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you for writing the example out!

Comment: Really understandable with the example

Answer (score 4):

I believe its used to emulate cartesian join.

From your query, the least modified value (**It will be just 1 element**) will be assigned to all the records of the left table.

**PS** : Left join is not much useful here. Might as well just use inner join