# Separate subselects to get multiple counts?

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, cross-join

I have this query:

```
SELECT  
(SELECT COUNT(media_id) FROM likes WHERE like_state = true AND media_id = ?) AS likes, 
(SELECT COUNT(media_id) FROM likes WHERE like_state = false AND media_id = ?) AS dislikes, 
(SELECT media_views FROM media_thumbnail WHERE media_id = ?) AS views;
```

It works fine but I'm not sure if this is the best way. Any recommendations?

I don't think this requires any explanation, but... It counts how many likes, or dislikes are in function of the `like_state` (`true` = like, `false` = dislike) and returns the view count of the associated video.

Comment: Could you run explain analyze on that query?

Comment: In what sense "the best way"? Are there any problems with this query, e.g. it works too slowly?

Comment: No, it doesn't I just wanna know if there is another way. What explain analyze is?

Comment: Postgres version and table definitions showing data types and constraints might be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely faster to use a single `SELECT` with two counts on table `likes` instead of two separate `SELECT`:

```
SELECT COUNT(    like_state OR NULL) AS likes
     , COUNT(NOT like_state OR NULL) AS dislikes
     ,(SELECT media_views FROM media_thumbnail WHERE media_id = ?) AS views
FROM   likes
WHERE  media_id = ?;
```

There are corner-case ***differences*** between this query with an uncorrelated subquery, your original query with two implicit `CROSS JOIN` (a comma `,` in the `FROM` list is almost identical to a `CROSS JOIN`) as well as Gordon's answer with a `CROSS JOIN` to the last subquery.

- [What does [FROM x, y] mean in Postgres?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167201/what-does-from-x-y-mean-in-postgres/167217#167217)

The first two subqueries *always* return a row, so a `CROSS JOIN` cannot eliminate the result.
But the third query might not find the given `media_id` in table `media_thumbnail` and return ***no row***. A `CROSS JOIN` to that results in `no row` for the whole query.

My query with a subquery in the `SELECT` list converts *no row* to a null value and still returns a result row. The same could be achieved with `LEFT JOIN ... ON true`:

- [JOIN (SELECT ... ) ue ON 1=1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35374860/join-select-ue-on-1-1/35375634#35375634)
- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

My subquery in the `SELECT` raises an exception if it returns more than one row - which cannot happen if `media_thumbnail.media_id` is defined `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY`, and probably *should* not happen in any case.

About conditional counts:

- [For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27558/for-absolute-performance-is-sum-faster-or-count/27572#27572)

The pretty and clean syntax would be with a `FILTER` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE     like_state) AS likes
     , COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE NOT like_state) AS dislikes
...
```

A bit more verbose, but may be easier to read. Performance is basically the same.

- [Return counts for multiple ranges in a single SELECT statement](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93510/return-counts-for-multiple-ranges-in-a-single-select-statement/93522#93522)

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fine, although I would be more inclined to write it as:

```
SELECT SUM( (l.like_state = true)::int ) as likes,
       SUM( (l.like_status = false)::int ) as dislikes,
       MAX(mt.media_views) as media_views
FROM likes l CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT media_views FROM media_thumbnail WHERE media_id = ?
     ) mt
WHERE l.media_id = ?;
```

This saves the overhead of scanning the `likes` table one time.

Comment: Can you explain a little further why use a cross join?

Comment: It says: the column "mt.media_views" should appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregation function. I don't know how to fixed it.

Comment: @RobertRocha . . . It uses `cross join` to bring in a result set that has a single row.