# Multiple joins on the same table multiply counts

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, aggregate, jsonb

When I run multiple joins on the same table, the first join seems to be the only one to go through.

For example, I'll get results like this:

```
ID, NAME, 200, 200
ID, NAME, 150, 150
ID, NAME, 100, 100
```

Where obviously the ticket count is clearly not the same as the time entry count.

```sql
select 
    contact.aid aid,
    (contact.data ->> 'FirstName') || ' ' || (contact.data ->> 'LastName') username,
    count(ticket) tickets,
    count(time) entries
from caches contact
inner join caches ticket
    on ticket.name = 'Ticket' and (ticket.data ->> 'CreatorResourceID')::numeric = contact.aid
inner join caches time
    on time.name = 'TimeEntry' and (time.data ->> 'TicketID')::numeric = ticket.aid
where 
    contact.name='Contact'
group by
    contact.aid,
    username
order by 
    tickets desc
;
```

I should be getting results like:

```
ID, NAME, 200, 421
ID, NAME, 150, 312
ID, NAME, 100, 152
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  The results look fine to an outsider.  A db<>fiddle might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principal problem is the same as here:

- [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result/12464135#12464135)

A little more obscured in your case by nesting values in a `jsonb` column, but all the same.

Aggregate first, join later:

```sql
SELECT contact.aid
     , concat_ws(' ', contact.data->>'FirstName', contact.data->>'LastName') AS username
     , sum(ticket.tickets) AS tickets
     , sum(ticket.entries) AS entries
FROM   caches AS contact
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT count(*)::int AS tickets
        , sum(entry.entries)::int AS entries
   FROM   caches AS ticket
   CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT count(*)::int AS entries
      FROM   caches AS entry
      WHERE  entry.name = 'TimeEntry' 
      AND   (entry.data ->> 'TicketID')::numeric = ticket.aid
      ) AS entry  -- was: "time"
   WHERE  ticket.name = 'Ticket'
   AND   (ticket.data ->> 'CreatorResourceID')::numeric = contact.aid  -- numeric?
   ) AS ticket
WHERE  contact.name = 'Contact'
GROUP  BY contact.aid, username
ORDER  BY ticket.tickets DESC;
```

Assuming that `aid`, or at least `(aid, username)` is unique in the base table, we don't need the outer aggregate at all:

```sql
SELECT contact.aid
     , concat_ws(' ', contact.data->>'FirstName', contact.data->>'LastName') AS username
     , ticket.tickets
     , ticket.entries
FROM   caches AS contact
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT count(*)::int AS tickets
        , sum(entry.entries)::int AS entries
   FROM   caches AS ticket
   CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT count(*)::int AS entries
      FROM   caches AS entry
      WHERE  entry.name = 'TimeEntry' 
      AND   (entry.data ->> 'TicketID')::numeric = ticket.aid
      ) AS entry  -- was: "time"
   WHERE  ticket.name = 'Ticket'
   AND   (ticket.data ->> 'CreatorResourceID')::numeric = contact.aid  -- numeric?
   ) AS ticket
WHERE  contact.name = 'Contact'
ORDER  BY ticket.tickets DESC;
```

Not only does it avoid the primary error of multiplied counts, it also typically makes the query faster.

Related:

- [Multiple array_agg() calls in a single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27622398/multiple-array-agg-calls-in-a-single-query/27626358#27626358)

You have `INNER JOIN` in your original query, which should probably be `LEFT JOIN ... ON true` to avoid eliminating users with no valid entries. It's safe to converted it to a `CROSS JOIN` in my solution because each subquery level is guaranteed to return exactly one row (aggregate functions, and not `GROUP BY`). See:

- [JOIN (SELECT ... ) ue ON 1=1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35374860/join-select-ue-on-1-1/35375634#35375634)
- [Should I duplicate columns between tables to speed-up aggregations like SUM?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/274249/3684)

About the `LATERAL` join:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Casting to integer (`::int`) in the subqueries is optional (and assuming that counts will never be out of integer range). It avoids escalating to `numeric`, which is more expensive to sum up.

Why `concat_ws()`? See:

- [How to concatenate columns in a Postgres SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942824/how-to-concatenate-columns-in-a-postgres-select/19943343#19943343)

And do `data ->> 'TicketID'` and `data ->> 'CreatorResourceID'` have to be `numeric`? Would seem like they should be `integer`.

Aside: Normalizing your data model (at least to some extent) would probably help your cause. Joining tables on data values nested in a `jsonb` column is comparatively expensive, and can typically be made much more efficient.

Comment: This is invaluable guidance. I appreciate all the effort you went to provide this information to me. I'll read up on the provided documentation. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Can you please see if this works for you?  This is the method I use when different related record types are contained within a single table.

If there is an error for the first `case` column, then change the `numeric` casts to whatever type that `aid` is (likely `int` or `bigint`).

```
select case name
         when 'Contact' then aid
         when 'Ticket' then (data->>'CreatorResourceID')::numeric
         when 'TimeEntry' then (data->>'TicketID')::numeric
       end as aid,
       max (
         case 
           when name = 'Contact' 
             then concat(
                    data->>'FirstName',
                    ' ',
                    data->>'LastName'
                  )
           else null
         end
       ) as username, 
       count(*) filter (where name = 'Ticket') as tickets,
       count(*) filter (where name = 'TimeEntry') as entries
  from contact
 group by aid
 order by tickets desc;
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this out.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are joining along two separate dimensions and hence getting the wrong results.

If so, you can use `count(distinct)`.  This is a bit of a guess, but perhaps:

```
count(distinct ticket) as tickets,
count(distinct time) as entries
```

Comment: I believe this worked! I'm going to test a bit and read up on distinct selection. I appreciate your assistance.